# Replacing multi-array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm currently setting up a guild website, on one of the pages I'm fetching information from an off-site resource which returns the requested data in an array, looking like this:

```
[0] => Array
(
    [character] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name
            [realm] => Server
            [battlegroup] => Battlegroun Name
            [class] => int
            [race] => int
            [gender] => int
            [level] => int
            [achievementPoints] => int
            [thumbnail] => image
            [thumbnailURL] => url
        )
    [rank] => int
)
...
```

I have to admit, it's been a good while since I even dwelled in to PHP last, and I'm absolutely dumbfolded when it comes to translating values inside the array. (I knew once!)

What I basically want to achieve was to "translate", for example $arr['character']['gender'] from it's integer value to values I've set from another array.

```
$gender = array(0 => 'M', 1 => 'F');
```

I've tried a few solutions already but, I've come up empty handed.
I'm hoping some of you guys have any pointers for me.

Thanks in advance, nontheless!

Comment: If you want to get M or F, then `$gender[$arr['character']['gender']]` would do it.

Comment: Absolutely awesome, alexn! I knew I had forgotten about something important. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can try sample code given below..

```
foreach($arr As $index=>$arrs{
    $arrs[$index]['character']['gender'] = $gender[$arrs[$index]['character']['gender']];
}
```

thanks